# Textual similarity between two tags in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nlp, similarity

I want to rate the similarity between two tags. For example the words *technology*, *computer* and *chip* should have **high similarity**, a word like *food* should be low similarity.

Given the recent advancements in AI and more traditional approaches from NLP, how would you solve that problem nowadays in Node JS?

I tried to get the [Google News dataset](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/) from 2013 to run with [word2vec](https://www.npmjs.com/package/word2vec), but neither this or other of the word2vec libraries seem to be running with modern versions of node (or at least i didnt manage to make any work yet with the dataset). There are also repos like [fast-text](https://github.com/loretoparisi/fasttext.js) or [Text Similarity Test (using TensorFlow.js)](https://github.com/AndriyMulyar/semantic-text-similarity).

Right now I'm wondering both which approach would be technically the best to fullfil my problem (also approaches that I didn't consider yet) *and* how to technically implement it in code.